# get all combination key codes from 2D array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to get the combination keys for an array - here the example:

```
$keys = array(
        array(
            'original',
            'section 1',
            'section 2'
        ),
        array(
            'original',
            'section 1'
        ),
        array(
            'original',
            'section 1'
        ),
        array(
            'original',
            'section 1',
            'section 2'
        ),
        array(
            'original',
            'section 1'
        )
);
```

all original sections would be 00000 (5 digits because of 5 different arrays, but there can be 1 to n arrays, not limited to 5) and variation #15 would be for example 01010. i basically want to get a list of all variations in a list with that key to get them. we assume that there are not more than 9 sections + original inside each array.

output should look like this:

```
array(
    array(
        "key" => "00000",
        "data" => array(
            "original", "original", "original", "original", "original"
        )
    ),
    array(
        "key" => "10000",
        "data" => array(
            "section 1", "original", "original", "original", "original"
        )
    ),
    array(
        "key" => "20000",
        "data" => array(
            "section 2", "original", "original", "original", "original"
        )
    ),
    array(
        "key" => "01000",
        "data" => array(
            "original", "section 1", "original", "original", "original"
        )
    )
    [...]
)
```

in addition to this it would be nice to have a good way to get it the other way too. giving the key 01010 and getting all sections back.

thanks!

Comment: I don't know others but to me your question looks too obscure.

Comment: I just want all the keys in a list based on the content of the array

Comment: So e.g. **'section1'** would return `11111` and **'section 2'** would return `2??2?`? The reason I used question marks is because index 0 is used by **'original'** in each array.

Comment: i added example output, probably explains it a bit better... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what i came up with:

```
$options = array();
$counter1 = 0;
foreach($keys as $values) {
    $counter1++;
    $counter2 = 0;
    $options[$counter1] = array();
    foreach($values as $key => $value) {
        if(isset($options[($counter1 - 1)])) {
            foreach($options[($counter1 - 1)] as $old_val) {
                $counter2++;
                $old_array = $old_val['data'];
                array_push($old_array, $value);
                $options[$counter1][$counter2] = array();
                $options[$counter1][$counter2]['key'] = $old_val['key'] . $key;
                $options[$counter1][$counter2]['data'] = $old_array;
            }
        }
        else {
            $counter2++;
            $options[$counter1][$counter2] = array();
            $options[$counter1][$counter2]['key'] = $key;
            $options[$counter1][$counter2]['data'] = array($value);
        }
    }
}
$all_options = end($options);
```

You get 72 results which is correct because it is 3 * 2 * 2 * 3 * 2 = 72

Comment: nice! yes, this is actually exactly what I want! - can you look at the updated post above and check out the example output? you think this is somehow possible?

Comment: Not sure if that is the most efficient way of doing it but it works.